# how to use MdPersianDateTime

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

Here is my code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#calan').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
                Placement: 'botto', 
            Trigger: 'focus', 
        EnableTimePicker: true, 
        TargetSelector: '', 
        GroupId: '', 
        ToDate: false, 
        FromDate: false, 
        });
    </scrip>
```

How to use MdPersianDateTime to date in input.

Comment: $('#id').MdPersianDateTimePicker({ 
  targetTextSelector: '#inputTextDate1',
  targetDateSelector: '#inputHiddenDate1',
});

Comment: please refer below link https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

according to [PersianDateTimePicker Documents](https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker) 
you can use it by

```
`$('#id').MdPersianDateTimePicker({targetTextSelector: '#inputTextDate1',targetDateSelector: '#inputHiddenDate1',});`
```

just 
add these files to you html:

```
<link href="/dist/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/dist/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

I suggest to add scripts at the end of body tag and after jQuery library.
for Options and Functions you can refer to document